# Advice on creating specific data type in CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, relationship

I have a model called `Company` which contains a field called `type`. Based on that type, I'd like to offer the user a list of checkboxes to select to add more data about their type. To be more specific, based on their business type, I'd like to offer a range of services which they can check off if they provide.

What would be the best method to achieve this? Do I add a new field called `services` and implode/explode the options there? Or do I set up a database relation?

The list of business types and services is fairly static, something I would typically use an array for as opposed to a database table.

Any input would be super.

Comment: It depends on the scale (ie, how many business types there are, and how many services there are for each type), and also on how often they'll change. If they'll change often, and there are lots of them, use a database relation. If there's only a few and they won't change often, it's easier to hard-code it. Update your question to give an indication of the number of services and types.

Comment: Thanks @joshua.paling. Answer updated, but to repeat, fairly static list of business types and services.

Comment: OK, the data is static. What about quantity? How many 'services' are there in total? 5? 20? 100? And what about how many 'services' for a particular business 'type'?

Comment: About 4 services for each business type.

Comment: You forgot to add - how many 'services' are there in total (ie, across all business types)? (and if I were you I'd add all that info; ie, number of services total, number of services per business, is there any overlap - ie, is any one service relevant to multiple business types?, and lastly, number of business types, to your original question. This info is important to know in deciding on the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Starts from the beginning adding field name `services` in the existing table wouldn't be create problem because of low data in the table, but when more and more data would be inserted in the table that will effect `communication` goes to decreases that's means your data execution time will getting more when `type` and `services` lives in common table, It would better when both stay differently, in this case for `queue` data execution time will be less, and performance would be increase.

**Note:-** My English is poor so please feel free for editing and also suggest me my mistakes :)